Using roslibpy to run navigation2 actions
I am using ROS2 Humble and the Navigation2 package. I want to use the Navigation2 actions via websocket, ideally using roslibpy. Doing this over websocket is important for my project, so I cannot use rclpy as in nav2_simple_commander.
Specifically, I am using the Turtlebot3 example and am trying to run the action /navigate_to_pose.
The important code is as follows (the goal message is removed for brevity):
rosbridgeclient = roslibpy.Ros(host="localhost", port=9090)

navigate_to_pose_client = roslibpy.actionlib.ActionClient(
    rosbridgeclient,
    "/navigate_to_pose",
    "nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPose",
)

navigate_to_pose_goal = roslibpy.actionlib.Goal(
    navigate_to_pose_client,
    roslibpy.Message(...)
)

navigate_to_pose_goal.send(result_callback)

I get the following logs and errors:
2024-06-05 12:08:31,478 DEBUG roslibpy comm.send_ros_message:48 - Sending ROS message|<pre>b'{"op": "advertise", "id": "advertise:/navigate_to_pose/goal:3", "type": "nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPoseGoal", "topic": "/navigate_to_pose/goal", "latch": false, "queue_size": 100}'</pre>
2024-06-05 12:08:31,478 DEBUG roslibpy comm.send_ros_message:48 - Sending ROS message|<pre>b'{"op": "advertise", "id": "advertise:/navigate_to_pose/cancel:4", "type": "actionlib_msgs/GoalID", "topic": "/navigate_to_pose/cancel", "latch": false, "queue_size": 100}'</pre>
2024-06-05 12:08:31,478 DEBUG roslibpy comm.send_ros_message:48 - Sending ROS message|<pre>b'{"op": "subscribe", "id": "subscribe:/navigate_to_pose/status:5", "type": "actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray", "topic": "/navigate_to_pose/status", "compression": "none", "throttle_rate": 0, "queue_length": 0}'</pre>
2024-06-05 12:08:31,478 DEBUG roslibpy comm.send_ros_message:48 - Sending ROS message|<pre>b'{"op": "subscribe", "id": "subscribe:/navigate_to_pose/feedback:6", "type": "nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPoseFeedback", "topic": "/navigate_to_pose/feedback", "compression": "none", "throttle_rate": 0, "queue_length": 0}'</pre>
2024-06-05 12:08:31,478 DEBUG roslibpy comm.send_ros_message:48 - Sending ROS message|<pre>b'{"op": "subscribe", "id": "subscribe:/navigate_to_pose/result:7", "type": "nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPoseResult", "topic": "/navigate_to_pose/result", "compression": "none", "throttle_rate": 0, "queue_length": 0}'</pre>
[rosbridge_websocket.py-7] [ERROR] [1717603711.596269988] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client c88476e6-d1a9-40a9-8714-fff72f8145a5] [id: advertise:/navigate_to_pose/goal:3] advertise: Unable to import msg class NavigateToPoseGoal from package nav2_msgs. Caused by module 'nav2_msgs.msg' has no attribute 'NavigateToPoseGoal'
[rosbridge_websocket.py-7] [INFO] [1717603711.604038834] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client c88476e6-d1a9-40a9-8714-fff72f8145a5] Subscribed to /navigate_to_pose/status
[rosbridge_websocket.py-7] [ERROR] [1717603711.604820846] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client c88476e6-d1a9-40a9-8714-fff72f8145a5] [id: subscribe:/navigate_to_pose/feedback:6] subscribe: Unable to import msg class NavigateToPoseFeedback from package nav2_msgs. Caused by module 'nav2_msgs.msg' has no attribute 'NavigateToPoseFeedback'
[rosbridge_websocket.py-7] [ERROR] [1717603711.605511887] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client c88476e6-d1a9-40a9-8714-fff72f8145a5] [id: subscribe:/navigate_to_pose/result:7] subscribe: Unable to import msg class NavigateToPoseResult from package nav2_msgs. Caused by module 'nav2_msgs.msg' has no attribute 'NavigateToPoseResult'

It does look like the messages that roslibpy are assuming don't exist in nav2_msgs, so I'm not sure what roslibpy is trying to do.
Am I using roslibpy incorrectly? Or is there something special about Navigation2?
Thanks for any help!
